# Extracting and copying files to local folder from a zip archive stored in a blob storage

Tags: c#, io, compression, zip

I have stored my zip file in blob storage . I already read archive from blob to stream
 .Code is as follows

```
string blobUrl = http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/usercontrols/ucProfileViewSMSIS.zip";
string containerName = "usercontrols";
Storage.Blob blobHandler = new Storage.Blob();
Stream blobstream = blobHandler.GetBlob(blobUrl, containerName);
```

I have three files in my archive . I want to write write those 3 files to my local folder .

How do I do this ?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#". Tags already accomplish this without making your title unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need an unzip library like [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) to unzip the files.  Under the [examples](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples&referringTitle=Examples) section, there is a method to unzip directly from a stream:

> Input from a stream. This example reads in zip archive content from an
>   input stream, then extracts the content for one entry to a filesysten
>   file. In this example, the filename "NameOfEntryInArchive.doc", refers
>   only to the name of the entry within the zip archive. This name is
>   used as the index in the string indexer on the ZipFile object. The
>   return value is a ZipEntry. The ZipEntry.Extract() method is then
>   called, which extracts the named entry to a filesystem file, using the
>   current working directory as the base. A file by that name is created
>   in the filesystem.

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(InputStream))
  {
    ZipEntry entry = zip["NameOfEntryInArchive.doc"];
    entry.Extract();  // create filesystem file here. 
  }
```